# Conectar o MySql que esta hospedado em outro servidor

Tags: php, mysql, centos

Tenho o Centos instalado com o php+apache funcionando

este centos é local mas eu quero usar este servidor local 
para conectar a um banco de dados mysql que esta em um servidor na internet.

tenho o firebird instalado neste centos, e eu consigo conectar nele normalmente.

Quando tento conectar ao MySql da este erro.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in
```

Obs. o arquivo de conexão funciona corretamente no servidor que esta na internet.

Comment: Se for um php muito novo essa função não existe mesmo. Tente `mysqli_connect()`. Obs: como você já tem algumas perguntas no site, acho que já é bom começar a formatar melhor e ser mais claro pondo todos os detalhes relevantes (versões, como está fazendo o teste, etc), para poder aproveitar melhor o site. Estes links aqui podem ajudar: **[ask]** e **[FAQ da Comunidade](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/699)**

Comment: Verifique as versões do php de ambos os servidores. Pode fazer da seguinte maneira, crie um arquivo com esse conteudo: `<?php phpinfo();`.

Comment: no phpinfo() só achei esta referencia ao mysql  '--without-mysql'

Comment: Talvez ajude http://stackoverflow.com/a/13825555/1342547

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que ocorre é que seu PHP não está com suporte a MySQL - baseado no --without-mysql.

Caso seja um ambiente Linux, você precisará instalar o pacote php5-mysql.

Lembre-se também de dois outros detalhes:

1. Seu usuário de MySQL precisa ter privilégios para acesso externo
2. Considere usar a classe PDO para manipulação com banco de dados